# yargs supports a minimum Node.js version of 12 - Jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins, webdriver-io, yargs

I have a problem with webdriver-io and jenkins. When I run my test cases on jenkins platform, I see an error message:
yargs supports a minimum Node.js version of 12. Read our version support policy: https://github.com/yargs/yargs#supported-nodejs-versions

but I have Node.JS 17.0.1. Where can be the problem?

My build failed. Test cases should run headless using chromedriver.